# FinalBuilder Server + FastMM4 example

Tags: delphi, fastmm, finalbuilder

When using FinalBuilder Server for continuous integration - what is the recommended way to run a suite of unit tests and establish a build pass/fail based on FastMM memory leak check?

Comment: How about definig EnableMemoryLeakReporting, setting ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown to True, and checking if {$AppName}_MemoryManager_EventLog.txt exists and is not empty?  I haven't posted as an answer as it seems a bit hokey and I'm sure someone knows a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of DUnit optionally link in FastMM4 and check for memory leaks after every test. This is visible in the GUI as an menu item.

As DUnit is open source, I guess this feature can also be used in a command-line test (TextTestrunner).

Also, DUnit can [return an exit](http://dunit.sourceforge.net/README.html) code if tests fail, so Finalbuilder only needs to check the exit code:

```
TextTestRunner.RunRegisteredTests(rxbHaltOnFailures);
```